# Php Jquery Set Multiple selected values from database

Tags: php, jquery, multiple-select

I have three multiple select menus.  I am trying to select the options returned from a database query.  It is not setting any options.  I console log the arrays returned by php and they are displayed as:["5233", "7148"]["5233", "5437", "5316"]["7029", "7852", "5525"].

I am not concerned about the form submission at this point.  I only want to display the values returned from the db query as selected. I am sure there is something I am missing but can't seem to figure it out.  I appreciate all the help I get.  Thank you in advance!!

First are my 3 database arrays that are created:
Second is my html:
Third is my javascript/jQuery:

```
I have three multiple select menus.  I am trying to select the options returned from a database query.  It is not setting any options.  I console log the arrays returned by php and they are displayed as:["5233", "7148"]["5233", "5437", "5316"]["7029", "7852", "5525"].
```

I am not concerned about the form submission at this point.  I only want to display the values returned from the db query as selected. I am sure there is something I am missing but can't seem to figure it out.  I appreciate all the help I get.  Thank you in advance!!

First are my 3 database arrays that are created:
Second is my html:
Third is my javascript/jQuery:

```
        <?
        $huntNum  = $hunts[$i][$fm_hunt_fields['__id']];
        $cookRole = 'Cook';
        $cookVols = get_volunteersByHunt($huntNum, $cookRole);
        foreach ($cookVols as $cVols) {
                //create new cook array that only contains ID of person
                $exCooks[] = $cVols['_id_acct'];
        }
        $guideRole = 'Hunt Guide';
        $hgVols    = get_volunteersByHunt($huntNum, $guideRole);
        foreach ($hgVols as $hVols) {
                $exHg[] = $hVols['_id_acct'];
        }
        $supportRole = 'General Support';
        $gsVols      = get_volunteersByHunt($huntNum, $supportRole);
        foreach ($gsVols as $gVols) {
                $exGs[] = $gVols['_id_acct'];
        }
        ?>


        <script>
        var existing_cooks = <?= json_encode($exCooks); ?>
        var existing_hgs = <?= json_encode($exHg); ?>
        var existing_gss = <?= json_encode($exGs); ?>
        </script>


        <form action="" name="vol-update" id="vol-update" class="vol-  update"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" id="id_hunt" name="id_hunt" value="<?= $huntNum; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action2" id="action2" value="1"  />
        <table class="tyhp-account">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="floatL cont_lft_side">
        <label for="cooks"><strong>Cooks</strong></label>
        <select name="cook[]" class="form-control vCooks" multiple="multiple">

        <?php
        foreach ($cooksArray as $cook) {
        ?>

                <option 
                <?
                if (in_array($cook['ID'], $exCooks)) {
                        echo "selected='selected'";
                }
        ?>
                value="<?= $cook['ID']; ?>" >
                <?= $cook['name_last'] . $cook['name_first']; ?>
                </option>

                <?
        }
        ?>

        </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatL cont_lft_side">
        <label for="hunt_guides"><strong>Hunt Guides</strong></label>
        <select name="huntGuide[]" class="form-control vHg" multiple="multiple">

        <?php
        foreach ($guidesArray as $guide) {
                ?>
                <option 
                <?
                if (in_array($guide['ID'], $exHg)) {
                        echo "selected='selected'";
                }
                ?>
                value="<?= $guide['ID']; ?>" >
                <?= $guide['name_last'] . $guide['name_first']; ?>
                </option>
                <?
        }
        ?>

        </select>
        </div>
        </td>

        <?php
        $allVols = getAllVolunteers();
        ?>

        <td>
        <div class="floatL cont_lft_side">
            <label for="supp"><strong>General Support</strong></label>
            <select name="gsupport[]" class="form-control vSupp"  multiple="multiple">

            <?php
        foreach ($allVols as $allVol) {
                    ?>
                    <option 
                    <?
                if (in_array($allVol['__id'], $exGs)) {
                        echo "selected='selected'";
                }
        ?>
                    value="<?= $allVol['ID']; ?>" >
                    <?= $allVol['name_last'] . $allVol['name_first']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?
        }
        ?>

            </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" name="action" id="upVol" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update Volunteers">
        </td>
        <td> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

        //Volunteer information for hunts
        <script>
        var cooks = existing_cooks;
        var hunt_guides = existing_hgs;
        var gen_support = existing_gss;

        console.log(cooks);
        console.log(hunt_guides);
        console.log(gen_support);

        //Cooks multiSelect
        $(".vCooks").val(cooks);
        $('.vCooks').multiselect({
        columns: 2,
        placeholder: 'Select Cooks'
        }); 

        //Hunt Guide multi-select
        $(".vHg").val(hunt_guides);
        $('.vHg').multiselect({
        columns: 2,
        placeholder: 'Select Hunt Guides'
        });

        //General Support multi-select
        $(".vSupp").val(gen_support);
        $('.vSupp').multiselect({
        columns: 2,
        placeholder: 'Select General Support'
        });

        return false;
        </script>
```

Comment: They are there as class="form-control vCooks", class="form-control vHg", class="form-control vSupp"

Comment: Help!  Can anyone help me here?